# PWA - Current page does not respond with a 200 when offline

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, caching, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

My lighthouse report keeps failing - It works when i test it myself though and it works fine offline. Can anyone see why?

```
    self.addEventListener('fetch',(e)=>{
    
      e.respondWith(handleRequest(e.request))
    
    })
    
    async function handleRequest(req){
    let res = false;
    
    try{
      res = await fetch(req);
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
    
     const cache = await caches.open(cacheName)
    
    if(res){
      console.log('yah');
       await cache.put(req, res.clone())
       return res;
    
     }else{
       console.log('nah');
        res = cache.match(req)
       res.status = 200;
       return res
     }
```

Comment: Have you tried going offline through dev tools in the applications -> service workers tab?

Comment: Yeah, It works fine when offlline